# $\psi^{−1}(0)$ =:  is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ \psi : \mathbb{R}^{+1} → \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that $\nabla \psi $ () $\neq 0$ $\forall x \in \psi^{−1}(0) =: M$. Show that  is a smooth manifold of dimension k.

I was thinking along the lines of :

M := {x $\in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ : $\psi(x) = 0$}. Furthermore $\forall p \in M$
$\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^{k+1}} \neq 0 $ thus $\exists $ a nbhd U of p in M, an open subset V in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$  and a smooth function $\varphi$ : V $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ st $ x = (y,z) \in M \cap U $ $\iff$ $ z=\varphi(y)$, $y\in V$.
This is the implicit function thm and then by definition we have that M is a surface because :

for any $p \in M$ $\exists $ an open set $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth map $\varphi : V \rightarrow M$ st :
1)$\varphi(V) = U$ is a nbhd of p in M
2) $\varphi : V \rightarrow U$ is a homeo
3) $D_q\varphi$ : $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1} $is injective $\forall q \in V$.

Could someone please tell me if my reasoning is correct?

Comment: This is not correct since your first claim is false. The map $(x^1,\ldots,x^{k+1})\mapsto x^1$ has nowhere vanishing gradient but its $(k+1)$th partial derivative is identically $0$.

Comment: But what you can do: choose a point $p$ in $M$ and an index $r$ such that $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x^r} \neq 0$ in $p$. By reordering the coordinates you may even assume $r=k+1$. Then continue with a local argument.

Comment: If I switch for the local argument, the rest is then correct?

Comment: @PeterCar Yes. An index $j_0$ such that $\langle \nabla \psi(p),e_{j_0}\rangle \neq 0$ gives you, with the help of the implicit function theorem, that $\{\psi=0\}$ is locally, around $p$, the graph of a function smooth $x^{j_0} = \varphi(x^1,\ldots,x^{j_0-1},x^{j_0+1},\ldots,x^{k+1})$.

Comment: Which definition of smooth manifold do you use? Is it a smooth submanifold of some $\mathbb R^n$?